# Убрать текст из textbox при клике мышью C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

В `textbox` через свойство указан текст, появляющийся в поле ввода при открытии формы.
При нажатии на поле ввода нужно, чтобы текст исчезал.

```
private void txtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSearch.Clear();
}
```

Использовал данный код, но при открытии формы текст внутри поля выделяется, а при нажатии выделение снимается, но при этом текст не исчезает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Clear();
}
```

Рекомендую использовать сравнение, либо по предыдущему значению либо через Bool чтобы после того как пользователь ввел данные уже не стирались повторно.

Answer (score 0):

Код приводить не буду, только неписаную истину для новичков в windforms. Если вы хотите, чтобы по определённому нажатию\наведени\и т.п происходило какое-либо действие, то нужно делать это через события в свойствах необходимого вам элемента. Надеюсь, это кому-либо поможет.